# S-K basis Completeness in combinatory logic

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I was reading the following Wikipedia page on combinatory logic and am puzzled by the example that is given:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis
Using the given transformation T[], the term `λx.λy.(y x)` is converted to a SKI combinator.

Here is the first rewriting step:

```
T[λx.λy.(y x)]
= T[λx.T[λy.(y x)]] (by 5)
```

Where `5.` is:
`T[λx.λy.E] => T[λx.T[λy.E]] (if x occurs free in E)`

I am failing to understand why `5.` is being used here. In `λx.λy.(y x)`, isn't `x` a bound variable (meaning it doesn't occur free in `E`)?

Answer (score 0):

In `λx.λy.(y x)`, `x` is a bound variable and is thus not free. But in `y x`, `x` is free. The proviso of the rule refers to `E` without the lambdas around it.